# Troubleshooting htacess edits to whitelist .well-known folder for let's encrypt challenge Drupal 7

Tags: .htaccess, https, drupal-7, lets-encrypt, whitelist

I need to prove ownership of SSL in order to switch hosts and reroute DNS. I have the file in the .well-known/acme-challenge/ folder, but the folder is 403 forbidden so the test fails. The site is running Drupal 7 and I have the lets encrypt challenge module installed as well

I have tried editing the .htaccess to add `RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]` but this has no effect. I have tested the .htaccess file by adding junk text and did get the 500 error, so I know it is being used. What could be getting in the way of this edit? Do I need to restart a process on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by finding the .httpdconf for the domain on the server (not the main one for the server) and adding a  clause to allow specific access to that directory.
The verification files were then able to be found and site is launched now on new host and server.